Can H.264/5 bitstreams be tagged with chroma "interleavedness"?
My understanding is that a given H.264/5 bitstream is agnostic as to the pixel format of the pictures, at least in the case of interleaved/semiplanar (NV12/P010LE) vs 3-plane (YUV420p). Which is to say, it is not part of the H.264/5 specification.
However, it's obviously useful for the decoder (or the user of the decoder) to know how to deal with the picture, i.e. how to display it. Is there anywhere in the headers to tag the bitstream with this information? Or is it usually communicated in the container somewhere?

"Is there anywhere in the headers to tag the bitstream with this information?" Yes and No... (1) No, generally the data is expected to be in a 3-plane format. (2) It is "Yes" if you encode at High profile where you can set the "type" (chroma_format_idc) of the 3-plane data. The options are hardcoded so you must choose between 0 (monochrome) and 3 (YUV444p). You need to use some other number that your encoder recognises as meaning NV12. Or maybe the decoder itself has a known expected value for NV12? Check the API docs of your decoder as suggested in the main answer.

The pixel output (or input) format (NV12, YUV420, etc) is an implementation detail of the decoder (or encoder).
You should find the required information in the documentation of the codec API.
Sometimes codecs support more than one input or output format.
There is nothing the the compressed streams that will tell you what pixel format was used as input or what you can expect as output.
But the chroma subsampling is in the compressed stream. So you'll know if your video is 4:4:4, 4:2:2, 4:2:0 or something else.
